# Radial-gradient not working as expected

Tags: html, css, css-gradients

I want a perfect circle to be made in the middle of another circle using only CSS. For that I am using `radial-gradient` and below is my code

```
li{
    list-style : none;
} 
li:after{
     border-radius: 50%;
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    line-height: 24px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    content: '';
     background: radial-gradient(circle, #FFF, #FFF, #DC352E 30%);
 }
```

My HTML structure is as below

```
<ul>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

But this code is not giving me perfect result.I am getting a circle in middle of another circle but the edges of the inner circle is becoming blurred. I want the inner circle to be a perfect circle as well without any blurry edges. Is there any solution for such issues?

PS: I want to use only CSS and no image/SVG

Here is a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0kLoLeer/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this http://jsfiddle.net/0kLoLeer/9/

**CSS**

```
li{
    list-style : none;
} 
li:after{
     border-radius: 50%;
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    line-height: 24px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    content: '';
   background: #ffffff; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #ffffff 24%, #dc352e 25%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(24%,#ffffff), color-stop(25%,#dc352e)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #ffffff 24%,#dc352e 25%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #ffffff 24%,#dc352e 25%); /* Opera 12+ */
    background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #ffffff 24%,#dc352e 25%); /* IE10+ */
    background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, #ffffff 24%,#dc352e 25%); /* W3C */
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

**CSS**

```
li{
    list-style : none;
} 
li:after{
     border-radius: 50%;
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    line-height: 24px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    content: '';
     background: radial-gradient(circle, #ffffff 0%,#ffffff 29%,#dc352e 30%,#dc352e 100%);
 }
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/luispa/0kLoLeer/4/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use the element border:

```
li{
    list-style : none;
} 
li:after{
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    line-height: 24px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    content: '';
    background:  red;
    border: 10px solid blue;
 }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1nm6gr6y/